# Store JSON to a Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON response that I would like to store in a map but do not seem to understand how to proceed with this. The JSON that I would like to store is:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "name": {
                "title": "Mrs",
                "first": "Claudine",
                "last": "da Mota"
            },
            "location": {
                "street": {
                    "number": 4066,
                    "name": "Beco dos Namorados"
                },
                "city": "Poá",
                "state": "Amapá",
                "country": "Brazil",
                "postcode": 55840,
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": "-72.3427",
                    "longitude": "112.5891"
                },
                "timezone": {
                    "offset": "-8:00",
                    "description": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
                }
            },
            "email": "claudine.damota@example.com",
            "login": {
                "uuid": "247261b1-80a5-428a-a906-a381efe93cb7",
                "username": "happyostrich285",
                "password": "2000",
                "salt": "bQwiFMAM",
                "md5": "c60b9d4138e4fb0d76182d3397ab35bd",
                "sha1": "d8e40944ed0d9d95f6c44d3d40f9d9e26e3cc04a",
                "sha256": "71d28bb93f2a386c23591c091c3b2bab2e1af89c3ad6d83af359398eb0637fe3"
            },
            "dob": {
                "date": "1974-08-05T08:07:07.202Z",
                "age": 47
            },
            "registered": {
                "date": "2003-11-08T05:19:12.790Z",
                "age": 18
            },
            "phone": "(98) 5277-4740",
            "cell": "(53) 0832-4652",
            "id": {
                "name": "",
                "value": null
            },
            "picture": {
                "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/89.jpg",
                "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/89.jpg",
                "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/89.jpg"
            },
            "nat": "BR"
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "name": {
                "title": "Mr",
                "first": "Lauri",
                "last": "Autio"
            },
            "location": {
                "street": {
                    "number": 7571,
                    "name": "Tahmelantie"
                },
                "city": "Pälkäne",
                "state": "Lapland",
                "country": "Finland",
                "postcode": 58979,
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": "40.0496",
                    "longitude": "-34.1528"
                },
                "timezone": {
                    "offset": "-12:00",
                    "description": "Eniwetok, Kwajalein"
                }
            },
            "email": "lauri.autio@example.com",
            "login": {
                "uuid": "1850e546-a847-4770-8cdb-48903c2874d1",
                "username": "beautifulleopard611",
                "password": "stinger",
                "salt": "LcnXkFBq",
                "md5": "0945ff84c37005726194b3f3c81bbb39",
                "sha1": "87945a6d1feae97e03cf92b166b0063b85328175",
                "sha256": "382f38e3f0105f0ddac0de9c10043f0928e471196d9e16204b4e2db0e00da62c"
            },
            "dob": {
                "date": "1958-06-04T08:53:39.167Z",
                "age": 63
            },
            "registered": {
                "date": "2008-04-08T08:12:25.490Z",
                "age": 13
            },
            "phone": "09-874-759",
            "cell": "041-737-00-52",
            "id": {
                "name": "HETU",
                "value": "NaNNA101undefined"
            },
            "picture": {
                "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/75.jpg",
                "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/75.jpg",
                "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg"
            },
            "nat": "FI"
        },
    ]
}
```

This is the approach I have taken but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';

class Profile {
  final String userName;
  final String name;
  final String emailId;
  final int timePeriod;
  final int age;
  final String nationality;
  final String number;
  final int streetNumber;
  final String streetName;
  final String city;
  final String country;
  final int postCode;
  final String picture;

  Profile({
    required this.userName,
    required this.name,
    required this.emailId,
    required this.timePeriod,
    required this.age,
    required this.nationality,
    required this.number,
    required this.streetNumber,
    required this.streetName,
    required this.city,
    required this.country,
    required this.postCode,
    required this.picture
  });
}

class ProfileProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Profile> _data = {};

  Map<String, Profile> get data {
    return {..._data};
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(extractedData);
    Map<String, Profile> map = {};
    extractedData.forEach((key, value) =>           //51:19
        map.putIfAbsent(key, () =>                  //52:13
            Profile(
                userName: value['login']['username'],  //54:32
                name: value['name']['first'],
                emailId: value['email'],
                timePeriod: value['registered']['age'],
                age: value['dob']['age'],
                nationality: value['nat'],
                number: value['cell'],
                streetNumber: value['location']['street']['number'],
                streetName: value['location']['street']['name'],
                city: value['location']['city'],
                country: value['location']['country'],
                postCode: value['location']['postcode'],
                picture: value['picture']['large']
            )
        )
    );
    _data = map;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The way I see it, the problem lies from 54:32 onwards and I now have no idea how to get past it to get the code to work. I find this approach easy to understand so ideally would prefer the answers to be in the same but other approaches are welcome.

This is the error I get. The line numbers with the errors are marked in the code:

```
E/flutter (20478): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (20478): #0      ProfileProvider.fetchData.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:profile_app/provider/data.dart:54:32)
E/flutter (20478): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:311:23)
E/flutter (20478): #2      ProfileProvider.fetchData.<anonymous closure> (package:profile_app/provider/data.dart:52:13)
E/flutter (20478): #3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter (20478): #4      ProfileProvider.fetchData (package:profile_app/provider/data.dart:51:19)
E/flutter (20478): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20478):
```

Comment: I suggest use https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json method for JSON serialization as this best practice in a flutter.

Answer (score 0):

the data type of "number" is int but you've added String.
I'd recommend to manage Models in a separately. also for the beginning use [json to dart](https://app.quicktype.io/) and then use that class name to decode or encode the json response.

```
Profile profile = Profile.Fromjson(json.decode('String'));
```

Comment: No Sir I  have not. Perhaps, if only you had seen my code properly for once.

Comment: I've shared the link of json to dart. paste your json response there, it will make models for you.
simply save that model in you flutter project. and use it for mapping.

Comment: Thank you and I'm pretty sure this will solve it. But do you think you can help me with the approach I have taken? It's just that I'm not referencing the values properly and I know that is where I've gone wrong. You'll see what I mean if you look at my code from the line that is commented as 54:32

Answer (score 0):

**Try out below Model Class**

```html
class ProfileModel {
  ProfileModel({
    required this.results,
    required this.info,
  });
  late final List<Results> results;
  late final Info info;
  
  ProfileModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    results = List.from(json['results']).map((e)=>Results.fromJson(e)).toList();
    info = Info.fromJson(json['info']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['results'] = results.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    _data['info'] = info.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Results {
  Results({
    required this.gender,
    required this.name,
    required this.location,
    required this.email,
    required this.login,
    required this.dob,
    required this.registered,
    required this.phone,
    required this.cell,
    required this.id,
    required this.picture,
    required this.nat,
  });
  late final String gender;
  late final Name name;
  late final Location location;
  late final String email;
  late final Login login;
  late final Dob dob;
  late final Registered registered;
  late final String phone;
  late final String cell;
  late final Id id;
  late final Picture picture;
  late final String nat;
  
  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    gender = json['gender'];
    name = Name.fromJson(json['name']);
    location = Location.fromJson(json['location']);
    email = json['email'];
    login = Login.fromJson(json['login']);
    dob = Dob.fromJson(json['dob']);
    registered = Registered.fromJson(json['registered']);
    phone = json['phone'];
    cell = json['cell'];
    id = Id.fromJson(json['id']);
    picture = Picture.fromJson(json['picture']);
    nat = json['nat'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['gender'] = gender;
    _data['name'] = name.toJson();
    _data['location'] = location.toJson();
    _data['email'] = email;
    _data['login'] = login.toJson();
    _data['dob'] = dob.toJson();
    _data['registered'] = registered.toJson();
    _data['phone'] = phone;
    _data['cell'] = cell;
    _data['id'] = id.toJson();
    _data['picture'] = picture.toJson();
    _data['nat'] = nat;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Name {
  Name({
    required this.title,
    required this.first,
    required this.last,
  });
  late final String title;
  late final String first;
  late final String last;
  
  Name.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    title = json['title'];
    first = json['first'];
    last = json['last'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['first'] = first;
    _data['last'] = last;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Location {
  Location({
    required this.street,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.country,
    required this.postcode,
    required this.coordinates,
    required this.timezone,
  });
  late final Street street;
  late final String city;
  late final String state;
  late final String country;
  late final int? postcode;
  late final Coordinates coordinates;
  late final Timezone timezone;
  
  Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    street = Street.fromJson(json['street']);
    city = json['city'];
    state = json['state'];
    country = json['country'];
    postcode = json['postcode'];
    coordinates = Coordinates.fromJson(json['coordinates']);
    timezone = Timezone.fromJson(json['timezone']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['street'] = street.toJson();
    _data['city'] = city;
    _data['state'] = state;
    _data['country'] = country;
    _data['postcode'] = postcode;
    _data['coordinates'] = coordinates.toJson();
    _data['timezone'] = timezone.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Street {
  Street({
    required this.number,
    required this.name,
  });
  late final int number;
  late final String name;
  
  Street.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    number = json['number'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['number'] = number;
    _data['name'] = name;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Coordinates {
  Coordinates({
    required this.latitude,
    required this.longitude,
  });
  late final String latitude;
  late final String longitude;
  
  Coordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    latitude = json['latitude'];
    longitude = json['longitude'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['latitude'] = latitude;
    _data['longitude'] = longitude;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Timezone {
  Timezone({
    required this.offset,
    required this.description,
  });
  late final String offset;
  late final String description;
  
  Timezone.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    offset = json['offset'];
    description = json['description'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['offset'] = offset;
    _data['description'] = description;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Login {
  Login({
    required this.uuid,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
    required this.salt,
    required this.md5,
    required this.sha1,
    required this.sha256,
  });
  late final String uuid;
  late final String username;
  late final String password;
  late final String salt;
  late final String md5;
  late final String sha1;
  late final String sha256;
  
  Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    uuid = json['uuid'];
    username = json['username'];
    password = json['password'];
    salt = json['salt'];
    md5 = json['md5'];
    sha1 = json['sha1'];
    sha256 = json['sha256'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['uuid'] = uuid;
    _data['username'] = username;
    _data['password'] = password;
    _data['salt'] = salt;
    _data['md5'] = md5;
    _data['sha1'] = sha1;
    _data['sha256'] = sha256;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Dob {
  Dob({
    required this.date,
    required this.age,
  });
  late final String date;
  late final int age;
  
  Dob.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    date = json['date'];
    age = json['age'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['date'] = date;
    _data['age'] = age;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Registered {
  Registered({
    required this.date,
    required this.age,
  });
  late final String date;
  late final int age;
  
  Registered.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    date = json['date'];
    age = json['age'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['date'] = date;
    _data['age'] = age;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Id {
  Id({
    required this.name,
     this.value,
  });
  late final String name;
  late final String? value;
  
  Id.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    name = json['name'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['value'] = value;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Picture {
  Picture({
    required this.large,
    required this.medium,
    required this.thumbnail,
  });
  late final String large;
  late final String medium;
  late final String thumbnail;
  
  Picture.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    large = json['large'];
    medium = json['medium'];
    thumbnail = json['thumbnail'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['large'] = large;
    _data['medium'] = medium;
    _data['thumbnail'] = thumbnail;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Info {
  Info({
    required this.seed,
    required this.results,
    required this.page,
    required this.version,
  });
  late final String seed;
  late final int results;
  late final int page;
  late final String version;
  
  Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    seed = json['seed'];
    results = json['results'];
    page = json['page'];
    version = json['version'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['seed'] = seed;
    _data['results'] = results;
    _data['page'] = page;
    _data['version'] = version;
    return _data;
  }
}
```